# можно ли как то вызвать функцию, подставив в название функции переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

прошу научить

Есть AJAX код, который работает. При возврате ответа, разбираю результат, и в соответствии с результатом я вызываю опр. функцию. Все вроде ничего, но если функций более 20ти, то ELSE IF в коде становиться слишком много

Вопрос: можно ли как то вызвать функцию, подставив в название функции переменную?

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"",
    data:myJson,
    success:function(html){
        myReturn=JSON.parse(html);
        if(myReturn.status=="ok"){
            if(myReturn.router=="fx1"){
                function_fx1(myReturn.data);
            }else if(myReturn.router=="fx2"){
                function_fx2(myReturn.data);
            }else if(myReturn.router=="fx3"){
                function_fx3(myReturn.data);
            }else{

            }
         }
     }
})
```

Comment: Как на счет вызывать лишь одну функцию передавая в нее параметр, а уже в ней свитчем делить логику выполнения на разные этапы?

Comment: можно, но будет тоже самое в плане длинны кода, хотел узнать можно ли сократить

Comment: Можно было бы сократить видя примерный код вызываемых функций (`function_fx1, function_fx2, ...`), не ясно что у вас происходит в них...

Comment: это абсолютно разные функции, с разным кодом. ну по стандарту, авторизация, показ каталога, так что интересует решить вопрос именно так как спросил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var functionHolder = {
  fx1: function(){ console.log("inside fx1"); },
  fx2: function(){ console.log("inside fx2"); },
  fx3: function(){ console.log("inside fx3"); }
};

var router = "fx2";
functionHolder[router]();
```

Comment: ну, хоть так. я так понял в название функции при вызове переменную не вписать )